# Magento Index : Update Required field always is set to YES

Tags: magento-1.8, indexing

I am not very much sure about how Magento Indexing works, But "Update Required" field is set to "Yes" immediately after i am done with re-indexing all indexes.

[image]

I have few queries regarding indexing

- On what condition status of an Indexer changes?
- Are various indexer available in Magento are dependent on each other?
- Why it shows    "Update required = Yes" even it is in "Ready" status.
  ?
- Is indexing    executed  on daily basis?If yes, then from where we
  can change time     of its execution?
- If a store receives couple of thousand request to update inventory
  via Soap API, do indexer are executed and updated  for every request
  which is received to update inventory of a product?

Your valuable input are much appreciated.

Thank You.

Answer (score 2):

> On what condition status of an Indexer changes?

Anything that triggers the event. For more information see below.

> Are various indexer available in Magento are dependent on each other?

Yes and no. You technically don't need one for the other, but performance and other issue will arise by not using them jointly.

> Why it shows "Update required = Yes" even it is in "Ready" status. ?

One show the Status that needs to be updated. The "Ready" status just means its available to. When it's not available it will say processing or error.

> Is indexing executed on daily basis?If yes, then from where we can
>   change time of its execution?

It depends, you have to Update on Save. So on every save of the indexing event.
There is also manual if you want to manually do it or
there is tools out there that can run on cron as well.

> If a store receives couple of thousand request to update inventory via
>   Soap API, do indexer are executed and updated for every request which
>   is received to update inventory of a product?

Yes, it will update the indexer, however, based on you setting is how it will fire. It's important to make sure that your store is getting the newest results. However, resources are used so just keep that in mind.

[How indexing works in magento](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/22157/how-indexing-works-in-magento/22166)

There is a lot of great information out there for this as well.
Let me know if you have any other questions.