# Would using flat tables generated by Magento for analytics (using Django) be a good idea?

Tags: ce-1.7.0.2, database, indexing, flat-catalog

**Background**

I am building an analytics platform on top of an already existing Magento Ecommerce using Python/Django. In this app, I need to show stuff like Total order value, Average order size etc. for certain time frames. Before we go ahead, keep in mind that this analytics engine *need not* show stuff real time. (They are allowed to be *little* outdated depending on the timeframe we would be seeing.).

I am not sure whether I could've used the Magento API for this job, but I just wanted to develop this pretty quickly and I wanted to use the framework I am more comfortable with. Also, connecting to the database made more sense to me than using the API of an already slow site.

**So here's my question:** I am thinking of building this platform using the [indexes (flat tables) generated by Magento](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/22157/how-indexing-works-in-magento/22166#22166), but I am not sure how (often) these tables get generated, and whether this would be a good idea or not? What problems could I run into in the future if I do this?

If anyone did something like this before, please share your experiences. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have built this thing, and it's working fine. The tables are generated by Magento quite often, and if anyone is going to do a similar thing, it shouldn't create much of a problem.