# Magento 2 Reindexing - One or more indexers are invalid. Make sure your Magento cron job is running

Tags: magento2, reindex, cli

I couldn't find the way to do reindexing in mass actions on magento 2.

Seems like you need to run it from cronjob. Is there an alternative way to reindex data in magento 2 from backend or command line just like it used to be in Magento 1.x (`php shell/indexer.php -reindexall`) ?

[image]

Comment: sorry but i am new in Magento. I have installed Magento locally to XAMPP, i am using Windows 7,and i would like to ask what can i do?? i get the same message,

Comment: @Alex4842 same thing here. Running Magento on Win 10. Found this: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/111132/magento-in-xampp-server-localhost-indexerreindex

Comment: You can reindex in backend via this guide https://www.mageplaza.com/kb/how-reindex-magento-2.html

Answer (score 129, accepted):

to reindex in magento 2, go to the CLI and then the root folder of your magento installation and run the below command :

> `php bin/magento indexer:reindex`

Comment: Just figured out from here http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/config-guide/cli/config-cli-subcommands-index.html

Comment: For those who are using mac, they can change directory to installation_dir/bin and write this command ./magento indexer::reindex

Comment: It says you can accept in 3 minutes xD

Comment: For cron, see also http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/install-gde/install/post-install-config.html#post-install-cron

Comment: I am getting parse error in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/Magento-CE-2.1.2-2016-10-11-11-16-47/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php on line 93

Comment: And the reindex isnt working, why is this happening?

Comment: By the way, you can leave the 'php' command out. Calling `bin/magento indexer:reindex` does the same. Might save some time if you're using CLI extensively :)

Answer (score 22):

Run this command in your CLI

> php bin/magento indexer:reindex

and if you want to reindex only one indexer then write following command:

> php bin/magento indexer:reindex indexer_name.

where `indexer_name` can be found by typing following command :

> php bin/magento indexer:info

Answer (score 7):

Here is how you can get things done using Magento 2 CLI indexing commands

Get into your Magento CLI command file available in Magento/bin directory
cd magento_folder/bin and run your command directly using Magento in terminal or putty.

Here is how it will work for indexing in Magento 2

##Get the list of available indexers in Magento 2##

```
php bin/magento indexer:info
```

##How to check the status of indexer##

The following command will get you the status of all the indexers whether indexing is required or ready.

```
php bin/magento indexer:status
```

You can also check the status of individual indexer: let's say I want to check the status of catalog_category_product

```
php bin/magento indexer:status catalog_category_product
```

##How to reindex all available indexing in Magento 2##

```
php bin/magento indexer:reindex
```

In case you fill memory limit, try this command

```
php bin/magento -dmemory_limit=2G magento indexer:reindex
```

Answer (score 4):

Use Magento CLI. Run `php bin/magento indexer:reindex` from project root directory.

Answer (score 1):

If any index is looping You can reset all index by using
`indexer:reset`
then use normal reindex

Answer (score 1):

To Reindex from command prompt run below command:

```
php bin/magento indexer:reindex
```

Above command should be run from magento root directory

Answer (score 1):

a. Reindex from Magento admin *sometimes not all indexers are reindexed using admin reindex > check also reindex via SSH

1. Go to System > Index Management and check indexers status
2. Select the items that are marked as "Reindex required" and go to Actions > Update on schedule

This will trigger a reindex for selected indexers.

Important: Sometimes not all indexers are reindexed using admin reindex even if time & date is showing as updated in Magento admin. We recommend double-checking the reindex process using the SSH/CLI reindex method presented below.

Reindex mode: You can set your indexers as "Update on Save" and store entities will be indexed when saving admin configurations or as "Update by Schedule" and indexers will be reindexed recurrently (default once / day). In order for "Update by Schedule" to work ok, make sure your cron jobs are running correctly on your server. Your hosting partner or development team can help you with the cron jobs configuration.

[image]

Done!

b. Reindex via SSH / CLI (recommended)

1. Connect to your Magento 2 installation at the root of your project. (usually in public_html or under yourmagentoinstallation.com/html)
2. Reindex all Magento 2 indexers using the below command:

`php bin/magento indexer:reindex`

You will receive a similar result as presented below:

Design Config Grid index has been rebuilt successfully in 00:00:00

Customer Grid index has been rebuilt successfully in 00:00:00

Category Products index has been rebuilt successfully in 00:00:00

Product Categories index has been rebuilt successfully in 00:00:00

Product Price index has been rebuilt successfully in 00:00:01

Product EAV index has been rebuilt successfully in 00:00:01

Catalog Search index has been rebuilt successfully in 00:00:01

Stock index has been rebuilt successfully in 00:00:00

Catalog Rule Product index has been rebuilt successfully in 00:00:01

Catalog Product Rule index has been rebuilt successfully in 00:00:00

[image]

3. Check the status of the indexers and identify indexers that still need to be individually reindexed, sometimes general reindex does not work for all indexers

   `php bin/magento indexer:status`

You will receive a similar result as presented below:

Design Config Grid:                                Ready

Customer Grid:                                      Ready

Category Products:                                 Ready

Product Categories:                                Ready

Product Price:                                        Ready

Product EAV:                                         Ready

Catalog Search:                                     Ready

Stock:                                                   Ready

Catalog Rule Product:                             Reindex required

Catalog Product Rule:                             Ready

[image]

4. Show the list of the indexers and corresponding indexer id that need to be used for individual re-index.

   `php bin/magento indexer:info`

You will receive a similar result as presented below:

design_config_grid                       Design Config Grid

customer_grid                              Customer Grid

catalog_category_product             Category Products

catalog_product_category             Product Categories

catalog_product_price                   Product Price

catalog_product_attribute              Product EAV

catalogsearch_fulltext                   Catalog Search

cataloginventory_stock                  Stock

catalogrule_rule                            Catalog Rule Product

catalogrule_product                      Catalog Product Rule

[image]

5. Reindex each indexer that has the status "Reindex required" using the below commands

   `php bin/magento indexer:reindex [catalog_category_flat]`

Example: `php bin/magento indexer:reindex catalogrule_rule`

```
php bin/magento indexer:reindex design_config_grid customer_grid
php bin/magento indexer:reindex catalog_category_product
php bin/magento indexer:reindex catalog_product_category
php bin/magento indexer:reindex catalog_product_price
php bin/magento indexer:reindex catalog_product_attribute
php bin/magento indexer:reindex catalogsearch_fulltext
php bin/magento indexer:reindex cataloginventory_stock
php bin/magento indexer:reindex catalogrule_rule
php bin/magento indexer:reindex catalogrule_product
```

6. Check again the status of the indexers using the command from step 2, now all indexers should be "Ready".

Done!

Answer (score 1):

On the Magento root CLI, run the below command

```
php bin/magento indexer:reset
```

Then run the below command

```
php bin/magento indexer:reindex
```

Answer (score 0):

solved with
`php bin/magento indexer:reindex`

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes to make it easy, you may want to re-index directly from the admin without involving cron (especially if you haven't setup your cron jobs and the site is still in development). In such cases, you can use the free extension [Admin Reindex [M2]](https://www.hungersoft.com/p/magento2-admin-reindexer) which allows you to reindex from the admin.

Answer (score 0):

You can re-index by using two different methods.

**1-    Re-Index from Admin Panel**
[image]

***To do so-***

Go to System > Tools > Index Management

Select the checkbox next to each type of Indexer to change

Select Indexing Mode from the Acton Dropdown
Click **Submit**

**2-    Re-Index Using CLI (Command Line Interface)**

Run the following Command in your CLI

```
Bin/magento indexer : reindex [indexer]
```

To view the list of Indexers-

Run the following Command-

```
bin/magento indexer : info
```

Still facing any issue/error, you can read this detailed article on

Answer (score 0):

**Magento 2 reindex using command line SSH:**
php bin/magento indexer:reset && php bin/magento indexer:reindex

**Note:**
For performance reasons, Magento recommends that you set all indexers to run on "Update by Schedule" and let cron reindex data. Otherwise, every time an object is saved reindex will happen and lead to high CPU usage and MySQL errors. As a best practice, Magento recommend that you use scheduled indexing.

Answer (score 0):

Use `Update on Schedule` instead of `Update on Save` to run the re-index process with CRON.

`Update on Schedule` is better than `Update on Save`. Magento also recommends using the `Update on Schedule` mode in production because it stores information about data updates and performs indexation by portions in the background through a specific cron job.

Whether the `Update on Save` mode immediately indexes whenever your catalog or other data changes. It can lead to significant delays and data unavailability during high loads. This mode assumes a low intensity of update and browsing operations in your store.

Check the below official Magento guide for more information regarding indexing.
https://docs.magento.com/user-guide/system/index-management.html