# One or more indexers are invalid. Make sure your Magento cron job is running

Tags: magento2, cron, xampp

Sorry but i am new in Magento and i would ask what to do, i install Magento2.0 locally on XAMPP (i am using Windows 7) and when i go on Dashboard ,i get this message: One or more indexers are invalid. Make sure your Magento cron job is running. I saw the answer in topic [Magento 2 Reindexing - One or more indexers are invalid. Make sure your Magento cron job is running](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/90510/magento-2-reindexing-one-or-more-indexers-are-invalid-make-sure-your-magento) , i have the same problem but the solution didn't work.

Comment: Do you consider installing it on vagrant? If yes, here is Magento 2 vagrant project especially for Windows hosts https://github.com/paliarush/vagrant-magento

Comment: i wasn't informed about that. Thank u so much for information! :) can i ask? in vagrant will it be faster, am i right? sorry if it is silly, but i am very new :)

Comment: because i noticed that Magento is very slow

Comment: Yes, it should be faster and moreover Windows is not officially supported environment for hosting Magento. Also it is much faster to set up environment (I use this vagrant project right now, it works pretty well)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to run from the project root: `php bin/magento indexer:reindex`

Comment: Thank u soooo much!!!!! it worked!!! :)