# How to Keep From Getting "System Message - Indexers Are Invalid"

Tags: magento2, indexer, magento-2.0.2

I spent all day yesterday attempting to make sure Magento 2.0.2 cron is setup correctly and working, that I fully disabled cache and that my indexers were working. Thought I was done.

Just logged in this morning to this frustrating message:

[image]

What am I doing wrong? How can I get Magento 2.0 to work? How can I get the indexers to index?

Comment: check this http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/90510/magento-2-reindexing-one-or-more-indexers-are-invalid-make-sure-your-magento

Comment: Ok, thanks @Manashvibirla. Yesterday, I had it in my crontab (running every minute). All was well. Then somewhere along the way someone posted it was not good to have it in cron. Right now, I don't care. I'm putting it back in cron. (Wow, is Magneto overly complex.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alternative solution  add `php bin/magento indexer:reindex` command at cronjob.

I have follow this and it has been working at any system

Comment: That's what I had in there yesterday. I just put it back in and all is well for the moment. Now the hard part...trying to upgrade from 2.0.2 to 2.0.4 without Magento Freezing and locking me out again.

Comment: avoid giving answers to already existing questions.!! mark it as duplicate instead

Answer (score 3):

You should Run CLI command :
`php bin/magento indexer:reindex`

Comment: Yep...Yesterday, I had it in my crontab (running every minute). All was well. Then somewhere along the way someone posted it was not good to have it in cron. Right now, I don't care. I'm putting it back in cron. Thanks @AnilSuthar

Comment: avoid giving answers to already existing questions.!! mark it as duplicate instead