# Magento 2.1.3 unable to reindex using SSH

Tags: reindex, magento-2.1.3, ssh

I tried the instructions under [Magento 2 Reindexing - One or more indexers are invalid. Make sure your Magento cron job is running](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/90510/magento-2-reindexing-one-or-more-indexers-are-invalid-make-sure-your-magento?newreg=9d2f8266baf948e5bea3fae15ec6cd76)

but am still unable to reindex. I ssh'd into my webserver and tried running the command that was suggested from the root, `php bin/magento indexer:reindex` but it didn't work, so I tried going to the directory 
`"blahblah.com"/shop/bin$ magento indexer:reindex`

-`bash: magento: command not found`
(I have a /shop directory where my files are installed)

and I tried magento `indexer:status` (and some others but am not able to run the commands, keep getting command not found)

I also opened up the file manager, found the magento file, opened it up and searched for indexer but am not finding it either.

Can someone help me to understand how I can reindex the status under the Index Management of my magento site? Thanks.[image]

Answer (score 0):

You either run the command as:

```
php magento indexer:reindex
```

Or you can make the magento script executable:

```
chmod +x magento
```

After making the script excutable you can run the script as:

```
./magento indexer:reindex
```

Your magento file should look like the following:

```
#!/usr/bin/env php
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © 2013-2017 Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

if (PHP_SAPI !== 'cli') {
    echo 'bin/magento must be run as a CLI application';
    exit(1);
}

try {
    require __DIR__ . '/../app/bootstrap.php';
} catch (\Exception $e) {
    echo 'Autoload error: ' . $e->getMessage();
    exit(1);
}
try {
    $handler = new \Magento\Framework\App\ErrorHandler();
    set_error_handler([$handler, 'handler']);
    $application = new Magento\Framework\Console\Cli('Magento CLI');
    $application->run();
} catch (\Exception $e) {
    while ($e) {
        echo $e->getMessage();
        echo $e->getTraceAsString();
        echo "\n\n";
        $e = $e->getPrevious();
    }
    exit(Magento\Framework\Console\Cli::RETURN_FAILURE);
}
```

Comment: I changed directory to the bin directory and issued the first command you suggested, php magento indexer:reindex but I received the following reply: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[', expecting ')'                                       then tried the second suggestion, chmod +x magento which I believe it took that command and then issued the next command from the same directory ./magento indexer:reindex      but received the same error as above.. Not really sure why it's not working          thanks for trying..

Comment: It sounds like when you opened the Magento file in your file manager you accidentally replaced a ) with a [ or deleted something. Are you able to upload your magento file? This new error would only occur if there was an error inside the file

Comment: @SteveBellinger first try to run `php bin/magento setup:di:compile` command and check what error and which file error it gives ? also check your log file

Comment: Thanks again for the help!
  
  @Andrew, it might be a problem with the script I originally ran which was on a hosted server- maybe the files I need aren't uploaded?

Comment: Thanks again for the help!
  
  @Manthan Dave, I tried running the command you suggested, but I walked the path trying to execute the command and here's the results:
  
  sbellinger@web18:~$ php bin/magento setup:di:compile
  Could not open input file: bin/magento
  
  sbellinger@web18:~$ cd www
  sbellinger@web18:~/www$ php bin/magento setup:di:compile
  Could not open input file: bin/magento
  
  sbellinger@web18:~/www$ cd anything.com
  sbellinger@web18:~/www/anything.com$ php bin/magento setup:di:compile
  Could not open input file: bin/magento

Comment: sbellinger@web18:~/www/anything.com$ cd shop
  sbellinger@web18:~/www/anything.com/shop$ php bin/magento setup:di:compile
  Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[', expecting ')' in /home/www/anything.com/shop/bin/magento on line 21

Comment: sbellinger@web18:~/www/anything.com/shop$ dir
  app            composer.lock    Gruntfile.js.sample  LICENSE_AFL.txt      php.ini.sample  update
  bin            CONTRIBUTING.md  index.php            LICENSE.txt          phpserver       var
  CHANGELOG.md   COPYING.txt      ISSUE_TEMPLATE.md    nginx.conf.sample    pub             vendor
  composer.json  dev              lib                  package.json.sample  setup

Comment: sbellinger@web18:~/www/anything.com/shop$ cd bin
  sbellinger@web18:~/www/anything.com/shop/bin$ php bin/magento setup:di:compile
  Could not open input file: bin/magento

Comment: sbellinger@web18:~/www/anything.com/shop/bin$ php magento setup:di:compile
  Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[', expecting ')' in /home/www/anything.com/shop/bin/magento on line 21
  
  sbellinger@web18:~/www/anything.com/shop/bin$ dir
  magento

Comment: sbellinger@web18:~/www/anything.com/shop/bin$ php magento setup:di:compile
  Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[', expecting ')' in /home/www/anything.com/shop/bin/magento on line 21
There was very little info in the access and error logs, definitely nothing of relevance. Is there a command to run logs from the command line to search for something specific (and if so from what directory)? Could it be that the pre-installed script doesn't have everything it needs and maybe I should just upload the full script (and this time with data examples) and install it by the console instead?

Comment: I'm not very experienced with Magento and this is the first time I've used the command line with magento so I don't know all the commands on it. So, I'm not sure what I should be looking for or what the normal behavior is when trying to run these commands. Does the above provide any clues as to why I can't run the commands?

Comment: @Andrew, I compared your magento file with mine and the only difference was on line 31 where mine says (    exit(Cli::RETURN_FAILURE);    ) instead of    (    exit(Magento\Framework\Console\Cli::RETURN_FAILURE);    )..  doesn't seem to be an issue though..