# Steps to change from flat structure to EAV

Tags: magento-1.8, eav, flat-catalog

We're having problems with `indexing` and I want to see if switching from the flat structure to EAV resolves it.

I can't find anything online that deals with switching like this (lots going from EAV to flat but nothing about the reverse process)

Is all I need to do make the changes in

> system > config > catalog> catalog > frontend

Anything else to consider? (I know about the performance downside)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Magento automatically adopts to EAV and Non-EAV, so you just need to switch it back from.

> system > config > catalog> catalog > frontend

Also, if you're having problems with indexing in the admin area. I suggest that you reindex it from the command line. See below guide on how to reindex via the command line:

[Magento reindex by command line](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/162166/magento-reindex-by-command-line)