# Index Management - Process taking a long time

Tags: reindex, enterprise-1.14, indexer

I have an issue with my Index Management job stuck in "Processing". I have read about it and found out that I can check if the reindex process is running by checking in MySQL, which I did. It is showing that the process is "working".
I can also do a SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST command and see if there are any inserts or delete commands against the catalog_product_index_eav table, which I have done and there is indeed a process running for the last 2 days...
So it appears that the process is still running but it has been like this for 2 days... However, I am doing random:
SELECT COUNT(entity_id) AS total FROM catalog_product_index_eav;
statements on the database and the number is not changing.

My questions are:

- Is it normal for this process to take so long? We have roughly 10,000
  products in the store.
- Can I stop this process, as it's preventing me from doing any other reindex job... and if so, would this have a negative affect?
- What would happen if I delete the files in /var/locks while the process is running? I guess it would allow 2 index processes to run at the same time?

Thanks

Comment: Did you tried indexing by command line ?

Comment: I didn't, I am worried about doing this as my knowledge of Magento is limited and this is a live store.
Could trying to run via command line cause any unwanted affects on my store or is this something I can try and not worry about breaking everything?

Comment: Just an update, there is no longer any selects or deletes running on the catalog_product_index_eav table, however when I do a "select * from index_process" on the magento db, it's showing me that the catalog_product_attribute is in status "working"...

Comment: actually indexing might be in process that's why you are getting that error , And if you do indexing with command line then just take care properly and indexing will be done

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/162169/49821 You may try this once

Comment: Ok so I went ahead and ran the command:
php /magentodirectory/html/shell/indexer.php -reindex catalog_product_attribute
This ran and everything was fine. But shortly after it ran again and is now stuck on a delete query for the last 20 minutes... should the queries take this long?

Answer (score 1):

Would suggest to stop the indexing and restart it. Go to project root directory from Command Line / Terminal and then enter below commands.

You can reset the indexing process by command

```
php bin/magento indexer:reset
```

After that reindex again,

```
php bin/magento indexer:reindex
```

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this issue in the end by killing the MySQL query that was running. I then changed the index jobs to **"Manual Start**" so that they don't run automatically.

I increased the amount of memory that was allocated to PHP and I am now able to run the indexes manually (via ssh), however, the Category Search Index has started to throw errors:

> PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 805306368 bytes exhausted
>   (tried to allocate 72 bytes) in /folder/folder/Table.php on line 111

I guess increasing the memory again will solve this error but I think there must be some other issue as we should not need to increase the PHP memory so soon after doing it this time.

Hope this can help someone.