# Magento 2.2 Not showing products

Tags: magento2.2

I have added new product enable it -> in stock -> assign category but still not showing on the storefront. Why?

Comment: Reindex all data, clear the cache and try again.

Comment: How to reindex data i am new on magento

Comment: Do you have the cronjobs correctly enabled? Check out https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/90510/magento-2-reindexing-one-or-more-indexers-are-invalid-make-sure-your-magento

Comment: @BunnyXudot  run the command on magento root folder                                        php bin/magento indexer:reindex