# What does each entry in index management actually do?

Tags: magento2, index

[image: My Index Management Screen]

I want to have a better understanding of what each entry does and what happens when it requires a reindex.
I've read the Magento Docs fully but they aren't known for breaking down things into the most understandable pieces. I know the difference/functionality of update on save and scheduled. Just not quite sure what it is doing behind the scenes.

Specifically, I do not understand what the entries for :
Rebuild Design Config index and Rebuild customer grid index are for.
Is there a directory I can locate these files in and change them manually?

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: have you check [this](http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/22157/how-indexing-works-in-magento/22166) answer?

Comment: Yes I did. However, my question still remains unanswered.. what are the design config and customer grid index for?  And where is the actually directory for these or the data found?

Answer (score 0):

Magento use flat table `customer_grid_flat` for customer grid so when you rebuild index for customer grid it will take data from eav tables and put data here in flat table for customer.

I can't see design config in my setup. It seems  to be available after some changes.